# Check if the CSV is empty

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a CSV file with just one column.

```
**Fruits**
Apple
Orange
```

How do I check if this csv is empty, I mean if there are no apple or orange listed in the csv file.

I am importing the csv with the following code, I am not sure though how do I check if the csv is empty after importing before executing further command.

```
$path     = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$csvPathforFruits = $path + "\Fruits.csv"
$importFruit = Import-Csv $csvPathforFruits
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
$importFruit = @(Import-Csv $csvPathforFruits)    
$importFruit.Length -gt 0
```

This will return `True` if there are any non-header lines in the CSV.

Comment: Its returning False, if I just add Apple

Comment: Updated the answer to always coerce the result into an array

Comment: Loading a text file that isn't a CSV will still give a value here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$importFruit = Import-Csv $csvPathforFruits | Measure-Object
$count = $importFruit.Count
```

$count gives the number of non-header rows. In this case;

```
**Fruits**
Apple
Orange
```

It should give 2. If it's 0, it'll be empty.